# DoMap in AfterPageLoaded throws exception when no internet connection

Tags: delphi, gmlib

When there is no internet connection or the connection is poor then after 60-70 sec an IE style dialog box appears with the message:

```
Script error
google not defined
```

Pressing yes or no AfterPageLoaded fires and the dialog appears again. Pressing yes or no again a memory exception thrown in the TGMMap.ExecuteScript function at the following line:

```
Win2.execScript(NameFunct + '(' + Params + ')', 'JavaScript')
```

I can reproduce it with the MegaDemo project as well. I'm using D6.
How can I test is the script initialized correctly in AfterPageLoaded function and do not call DoMap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, add a new issue at [code.google](https://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/issues/list)

Comment: ok, new issue added (GC 57)